# How to use the Capacitor Browser API

Tags: ionic4, capacitor

I am currently porting my project to Ionic 4 and wanted to replace the Cordova InAppBrowser with the Capacitor browser but with little success so far...
This is my page:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Plugins} from '@capacitor/core';
const { Browser } = Plugins;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-srd',
  templateUrl: './srd.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./srd.page.scss'],
})
export class SrdPage implements OnInit {

constructor() {
}

async ngOnInit() {
    const url = 'http://capacitor.ionicframework.com/';
    await Browser.open({'url': url});
}
}
```

There is no console output and the page stays blank.
Any ideas what went wrong?

Comment: Do you get the same result if you comment out the two lines in `ngOnInit`?

Comment: Well yes, then there is nothing that could be executed. In general the ngOnInit() method gets called just fine though as inserting a "console.log('Test');" does indeed write into the console.

Comment: Okay, I was under the impression from your question that the framework was failing to load entirely.  Perhaps the `Browser.open` call is silently failing.  Try removing the `async`/`await` and attaching a `.catch` to your returned `Promise` to ensure no silent failure.

Comment: Ah, I understand!  I added the .catch() but nothing changed and I still cant see any kind of error.

Comment: My only other idea would be to see if it functions as expected if you move the call to a different lifecycle hook (probably `ngAfterViewInit`).

Comment: I tried to change the lifecycle hook but it had no effect. But after playing around with it a few more times I suddenly noticed that my Chrome blocked a popup which was exactly the site I wanted to open. How embarrassing....  :(

Comment: A nice outcome nonetheless!

Answer (score 3):

This should work.
 Remove the quote around the first url:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Plugins} from '@capacitor/core';
const { Browser } = Plugins;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-srd',
  templateUrl: './srd.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./srd.page.scss'],
})
export class SrdPage implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    const url = 'http://capacitor.ionicframework.com/';
    await Browser.open({'url': url});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Browser } from '@capacitor/browser';

async openLink(Url){
   await Browser.open({ url: Url });
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const url = 'http://capacitor.ionicframework.com/';
await Browser.open({url: url});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: is there a way to access the url while the browser is open  ? i want to make some condition, like if url = www.ddd/com then browser.close();